# How to tree view category subcategory in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, view, tree

I want to generate categories and subcategories as tree view structure.

Example:

```
<ul>
  <li>cat_name_en</li>
  <li>cat_name_en
    <ul>
      <li>sub_name_en</li>
      <li>sub_name_en</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>cat_name_en</li>
</ul>
```

> **categories table::** id(primary), cat_name_en,
>
> **sub_category table::** id, sub_name_en, category_id(foreign key)

Table structure:

[image]

**Question is**
How to write join query in sql?

And how to display category with subcategory, as like nested `ul li` list.

Comment: ok ! but where is the question !?!

Comment: edited... question

Comment: the easiest way is to do 2 queries; one for retrieve all categories and once you get all the categories, foreach of them you should do a query to the sub_category table asking for the category_id equal to the id of the current category. Every time you cycle for a category print a <li>cat_name_en</li><ul> element, while foreach element of sub_category query print a <li> sub_name_en </li>, at the end close the </ul> and at the ond of all categories close </ul>